# Print@"~" prints a dash

Tags: front-end, fonts

`Print@"~"` prints a dash. Is this intended behavior? Do you think it is a bug? I'm running 10.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (June 29, 2014).

Edit: a screen grab at 125% mag to illustrate:
[image]

Screenshot from original author:
[image]

Comment: Ha, I'm guessing your Magnification isn't 100%, am I right? Is this the same issue: [31874801#31874801](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/31874801#31874801)?

Comment: No problem with `11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit)`

Comment: This is certainly a Windows font rendering or [hinting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Font_hinting) issue, not a Mathematica one. Try other font sizes or other fonts.

Comment: The issue occurs with 10.1/windows only if I set the magnification other than `100%` .  50,75,125 yield "-" and 100,200,300 yield "~".

Comment: see the issue like this too: (normal mag) `Style["~", FontFamily -> "Courier New", FontSize -> #] & /@ {13, 14, 
  15, 16, 17}`

Comment: That's only because `Print` outputs with smaller fonts. It won't fix this but you really should upgrade to at least 10.0.2.  It will fix a lot of other bugs.

Comment: @ChrisChiasson Are you sure this is a Mathematica problem and not a font rendering one as I said above? Have you tried the same in other programs with the same font?  (It's not clear if this is Courier New or a Mathematica font.)  v11 has another default font, but there's a high chance that with the same font on the same version of windows it will behave the same. So you might as well just change the font in your installed version.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/a/5526003/1004168 for changing the font.   I've found many fonts exhibit the same issue for *smaller* sizes / magnification but work ok for larger sizes.

Comment: The same thing happens with version 11.0.1 on Windows